fl_chart pie chart show me error on one item
https://i.sstatic.net/YjczQKBx.png
This is the imgae that its working, that is wrong
The pie chart works correctly in a new project but not in the existing one, despite using the same code. The internal white circle doesn’t show. I suspect a dependency issue but can’t identify which one. I’m using Flutter version 3.16.9.

Welcome to SO! Can you please share some code so someone can understand how and what you have build?

I think in your code you are not set centerSpaceRadius.
